# how laravel handle illuminate namespace

Tags: laravel, namespaces

As far as I know, namespace is used for preventing class, function, ... collision in PHP. In Laravel 8 when we create a model for example, the name space is `App\Models` and when we want to use this model, we have to use it like `use App\Models\MyModel`. My question is when we use `use Illuminate\Support\Arr`, why we don't use the full path explicitly `vendor\laravel\framework\......`

Answer (score 1):

It’s part of the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) auto loading standard which replaces the [PSR-0](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) auto loading standard. Composer compiled an autoload.php from your project’s and dependencies’ `composer.json`. As part of the bootstrapping process that file is included in the application and registers each namespace.